# How to stop c programing from rounding up decimal places

Tags: c

I declare a variable 'result' as float
And I initialized the value as result  = 4/3
The output am getting is 1.000000
How can I make it give me all the values of the decimal points and not just zero's

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 3):

`4/3` **is** 1. The arguments to that expression are both integers. You then assign the integer 1 to a `float`. That gives you `1.0f`, yes.

You'd need to write `4.0f/3.0f` so that the result is `1.333f` - that's floating-point division.

BTW, C typically uses "binary places" , not decimal places internally. You may see some rounding effects that would be illogical in decimal arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

`4` and `3` are considered as integers so the compiler uses an integer division to compute `4/3`.

You must define result as `float result = 4.0f/3.0f;`